# R - data profiling similar to pandas?

Tags: r, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I've done a bit of searching and a lot of the packages recommended do similar jobs but not quite as simple as I'd like.

Preferably I'd like a html output, and specifically, like from the pandas profile report, I'd want pretty simply a list of each variable with;

1. number(+ %) of missing
2. distribution

Closest I can find is DataExplorer using create_report and making a config to get rid of a lot of the plots, but the missing# is specifically weak in it's normal form because with a wide dataset the big "on one graph" is impossible to interpret.

Essentially, is there another package which does what pandas profile report does, giving missing# & distribution for each variable one at a time, or is there a way to alter DataExplorer to do so?

Comment: Does `summary(df)` met you requeriment?
Also it could be `broom::glance()` or `skimr::skim()`

Comment: Try `Hmisc::describe` as well.  There are _lots_ of packages doing that among the over 18k CRAN packages.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider suumarytools:

df |> summarytools::dfSummary() |> summarytools::stview()